# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING but JSON is correct

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, gson

I have searched the other related questions but am not able to find my answers.

This is my JSON: named `appointments.json`

```
   [
  {
    "title": "Primary Care",
    "text": "Schedule a Primary Care appointment online.",
    "image": "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Primary Care",
    "text": "Schedule a Primary Care appointment online.",
    "image": "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Primary Care",
    "text": "Schedule a Primary Care appointment online.",
    "image": "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"
  },
  {
    "title": "Primary Care",
    "text": "Schedule a Primary Care appointment online.",
    "image": "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png"
  }
]
```

Here is the list object class:

```
    @Parcelize
data class AppointmentsListItem(
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("title")
        val title: String = "",
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("text")
        val text: String = "",
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("image")
        val image: String = "") : IAppointmentsListItem
```

Here is where my error occurs:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
        .create()

private val listType = object : TypeToken<List<AppointmentsListItem>>() {}.type

    val apiList: List<AppointmentsListItem> = gson.fromJson("appointments.json", listType)
```

Where the heck is the STRING coming from?? My Json response is an array of these ListItems, I'm starting the response with a `[]` so why is it reading a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where the heck is the STRING coming from?

`"appointments.json"` is a string. Moreover, `"appointments.json"` is not a valid JSON string, as it starts with `a`, not `[` or `{`.

My guess is that `appointments.json` is supposed to be a filename. However, Gson does not know that, and a bare filename is useless regardless. You need to provide Gson with an `InputStream` or `Reader` on the JSON itself, whether that comes from, such as:

- `FileReader` (where you provide a `File` that points to wherever `appointments.json` resides)
- `InputStream` from `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`
- `InputStream` from `AssetManager` and `open()`

Comment: HAHA! Man so simple! I'm sure that was the problem, i will accept this answer once I add the FileReader and get it working

Comment: @Kyle: Make sure that you are using the correct method to get the root directory for your `File` (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). A bare filename like `appointments.json` has no meaning in Android. Where is this file located?

Comment: Yeah I'm having trouble finding it
it is located at `AppName/ModuleName/src/test/resources/appointments.json`


but doing FileReader(the path above) returns a file not found exception

Comment: @Kyle: I have not written unit tests that use Java resources, so I am uncertain what the process is to get the `InputStream`.

Comment: `InputStream = context.getAssets().open(assetName)`, set buffer, and read in..got it..Thanks!